# Fade out audio at the end of video using avconv with shortest option

Tags: audio, video, audio-processing, avconv

I'm using avconv for merging an audio file with a video file. I'm using a script in which the video length will vary from file to file. So, I use -shortest flag to stop audio abruptly at the end of the video. I want to fade out audio alone for 2 seconds at the end of the video. But, I don't know the exact length of a particular video.

```
avconv -i  inputvideo.mp4 -i inputaudio.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -shortest  videowithfadedaudio.mp4
```

What should I do?